# Does C#.NET have an allocation helper class similar to mine?

Tags: c#, .net

I have implemented the following class:

```
public class ClassAllocator<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public delegate T Allocator();
    T obj;
    Allocator allocator = () => new T();

    public ClassAllocator( T obj )
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public ClassAllocator( T obj, Allocator allocator )
    {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.allocator = allocator;
    }

    public T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if( obj == null )
            {
                obj = allocator();
            }

            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like something this simple & useful should be in .NET somewhere. Also, I realize that the class I made is somewhat incorrect. The class is designed to work with objects that don't have a default constructor, yet my 'where' clause requires it in all cases.

Let me know if there is something in .NET I can use so I can get rid of this class, as I would hate to continue using a reinvented wheel.

Thanks!!!!

### **UPDATE:**

I'm using .NET 3.5. Sorry I didn't mention this before, I wasn't aware it was relevant until a few good answers started flowing in :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [Lazy<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

> **Lazy<T> Class**
>
> Provides support for lazy initialization.
>
> Lazy initialization occurs the first time the Lazy<T>.Value property is accessed

Comment: The Lazy class is only in .NET 4.0, I'm using version 3.5. So I won't be able to use this class.

Comment: @Robert Dailey: Have a look at http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/06/09/ALazyInitializationPrimitiveForNET.aspx

Answer (score 6):

The [Lazy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)

Comment: The Lazy class is only in .NET 4.0, I'm using version 3.5. So I won't be able to use this class.